# How to make some loading text for HTML5 iFrame

Tags: html, iframe

I have an iFrame object that are defined like this:

```
<iframe src="iFrame SRC" frameborder="0" width="160" height="200" scrolling="no" longdesc="longdesc URL">
</iframe>
```

Now this frame took a long time to load, is it possible to make a loading text that simple says `Loading frame...`, and when the frame appears make the text go away? I tried putting the text right above the frame definition like this:

```
Loading...
<iframe ...>
</iframe>
```

It does stay on top of the frame but never goes away. How do you put a loading text for an iframe?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the iFrame in a DIV with a class for loading a back ground image.

```
<div class="iframe-loading">
   <iframe src="iFrame SRC" frameborder="0" width="160" height="200"  scrolling="no" longdesc="longdesc URL">
   </iframe>
</div>


 .iframe-loading {
  background:url(../images/loading.gif);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A long time ago I used to do this:

```
<iframe src="iFrame" etc. ...>  
Loading frame...
</iframe>
```

Comment: My solution in 2022 is like this: https://jsfiddle.net/hrv3e/fheorg5t/ (text with spinner)